# Use struct field as argument

Tags: c#

I have this class.

```
public class EmailManager
{
   public struct AttachmentFormats
   {
        public const string Excel = ".xlsx";        
        public const string Pdf = ".pdf";
   }
   private static bool SendEmail(string to, string from, ???)
   {
      /*??? is one of the AttachmentFormats*/
   }
}
```

When user wants to use `SendEmail`, I want to restrict them to use only one of the defined AttachmentFormats. Like

```
EmailManager.SendEmail("xxx","yy",EmailManager.AttachmentFormats.Excel);
```

Is this possible. If yes, how should I do it.

Comment: Define an enum, not struct.

Comment: Then, the value would be an int and then I have to write an extension method again. right. I thought this would be simpler.

Comment: int!! why? you will be acessing the Value as how you have mentioned in your question "EmailManager.AttachmentFormats.Excel" . To provide limited options I feel enum is the best choice. also within sendEmail () do you want to get ".xlsx" ??

Comment: Yes thats right. I am defining 'formats' in string, so they are verified in another function.

Comment: i am wondering why are you using struct there, when you can have class with static const properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need `enum` not `struct` :

```
public enum AttachmentFormat
{
     xlsx = 0,
     pdf = 1
}

public class EmailManager
{

   private static bool SendEmail(string to, string @from, AttachmentFormat format)
   {
      switch(format)
      {
          case AttachmentFormat.pdf: 
          // logic 
          break;
          case AttachmentFormat.xlsx: 
          // logic 
          break;
      }
   }
}
```

Other solution is to create interface and class that implements this interface :

```
public interface IAttachmentFormat {}

public sealed class PDFAttachmentFormat : IAttachmentFormat { } 
public sealed class XLSXAttachmentFormat : IAttachmentFormat { }
```

And then check for type inside SendEmail method :

```
   private static bool SendEmail(string to, string @from, IAttachmentFormat format)
   {
      if(format is PDFAttachmentFormat) // some logic for pdf
      if(format is XLSXAttachmentFormat) // some logic for xlsx
   }
```

Comment: I would have done that. But the values have to be int here and then some logic again somewhere to match those values to string. Directly having a string value in  a struct/or enum would have been simpler

Comment: @Qwerty added another solution that might better suit your needs

Comment: Guess it's not possible with struct and the other simple way is enum.  Using Interface is seems more complex and more lines of code than enum.Thank you though

Comment: @Qwerty Yes `interface` solution is more complex, but in some special cases, when for example you may require to implement some special logic inside the type then it's the only alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you want users of your class to call SendEmail, then it will have to be public.

Also, I echo early comments of using an Enum rather than a struct.  With implementation given by Aram Kocharyan above, the user could use your pre-defined strings but are not forced to.  There is nothing preventing them calling:

```
EmailManager.SendEmail("me","you","Any old string I can make up");
```

Using the enum method:

```
EmailManager.SendEmail("me","you",EmailManager.AttachmentFormat.Excel);
```